# What would happen if I create a .emacs file and edit it, even if I already have one?

Tags: emacs

I've spent a long time looking for my .emacs file and have yet to find it even after using the solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869909/what-to-do-if-i-cannot-find-my-emacs-init-file

Someone also said if I start up with emacs -Q (without the init file) and it looks different then starting up regularly, I already have a .emacs file. Because of this discrepancy between emacs and emacs -Q, I think I already have .emacs file, but I cannot find it. What would happen if I create a new .emacs file and edit it?

Comment: How about satisfying your curiosity by putting the following inside your `.emacs` file:  `(message "Hello @Goldname -- how are you today?")`  Then, save the file and restart Emacs and go to the `*Messages*` buffer and see if your new message is there.  If it is, then crack open a beer and celebrate because you have just located your `.emacs` file and verified that it is being read by Emacs.  You can only have one of them, not more than one.  So, do whatever you want with your one `.emacs` file.  Use it to customize Emacs to your liking, including loading additional files or libraries.

Comment: I want to add line numbers to all my text files, but I don't know if bad things would happen

Comment: The first step in using Emacs is to create a `.emacs` file in the home directory, or an `init.el` inside the `.emacs.d` folder in the home directory.  Get that squared away before you do anything else.  If you want to try out line numbers, just type `M-x linum-mode` in whatever buffer you want to use.

Comment: The .emacs file does not come with Emacs?

Comment: Emacs only makes the `.emacs.d` folder inside the home directory, but it does not make the `.emacs` file in the home directory unless you customize and save a setting.  You can customize some setting in the menu-bar like font, and then save the setting for all future sessions, and then Emacs will create the `.emacs` file with the new setting included inside the file.  Otherwise, just create the file manually yourself -- either a `.emacs` in the home directory, or an `init.el` inside the `.emacs.d` folder, whichever you prefer.  You can create the file using anything -- e.g., file manager . . .

Answer (score 1):

Note that `emacs -Q` will start emacs without any init files.  So the difference between `emacs` and `emacs -Q` may be due to a system-wide init file.  To test for just a personal init file use `emacs -q` (that's a lower case q rather than an upper case Q).

And one of the answers on that other question tells you about how to locate your init file: type `C-h v user-init-file RET` and it tells you about the variable that holds that info, including its current value.